# Multiple-entry Schengen Visa – can I enter the second time into another country?

Tags: schengen, schengen-visas, italy, multiple-entry

I have a multiple-entry Schengen Visa issued from the Italian Embassy. I have entered one time from Italy; can I enter into any other Schengen country during my second entry?

Comment: Welcome to the site Nohman. We are a site that tries to keep the number of almost identical questions down and there is one that is almost identical to yours. The answer there (yes you can enter through an other country later) is identical to the answers you would get here.